# How to prove positivity of $\int_{\Bbb R_+\times\Bbb R_+} x(x-y)P(x,y) dx dy $

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, multivariable-calculus, variance

I need to show that
$\int_{\Bbb R_+\times\Bbb R_+}x(x-y)P(x,y) dx dy \geq0$
where $P(x,y)=P(y,x)$ symmetric (potentially $P(x,y)\geq0$ everywhere).

Intuitively this seems obvious by splitting the integral along the diagonal. But so far I failed to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional hypothesis $P\ge0$ a.e. is necessary.

$$\begin{align}\int_{\Bbb R_+\times\Bbb R_+}x(x-y)P(x,y)dxdy&=\int_{y,h>0}(y+h)hP(y+h,y)dhdy+\int_{x,k>0}x(-k)P(x,x+k)dxdk\\&=\int_{y,h>0}\left((y+h)hP(y+h,y)-yhP(y+h,y)\right)dhdy\\&=\int_{y,h>0}h^2P(y+h,y)dhdy\\&\ge0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't fully understand what is going on there in the frist step (including notation)

Comment: In the first step I splitted the integral as you suggested, and made a change of variable on each half. In the second step, I renamed $y,h$ the variables $x,k$ of the second half, and used the symmetry.